# Existing solutions to edit NSManagedObjects via a UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In my iOS app, there are various Core Data entities that represent things like Appointments, Notes and Contacts.

I'd like the user to be able to edit selected attributes of each entity via a `UITableView`. Similar to the iOS Calendar app, when you click 'Edit', you're presented with a `UITableView` with editable values for Start Time, End Time, etc.

It's occurred to me that there could be a large amount of code re-use going on here, so I'm now considering creating a generic class, `ManagedObjectEditorViewController` that takes a managed object, displays selected attribute values within a table view, formatted according to their type, and allows them to be edited.

I can think of several neat ways of doing this, but before I spend a long time on this, I'm wondering if there's already something out there to accomplish this task?  It seems like such a frequently used approach that I can't believe there isn't already some open source code out there.

Anyone heard of, or used anything similar?

Answer (score 2):

I am about to do the same thing. Just started and works so far. A table that represents an `NSManagedObject` (Detail to a master view controller, has aspects of a master view controller itself.).

The whole table represents one `NSManagedOjbect`. There are fields and other controls that correspond with the simple properties.

There are to-one references where the referenced object is just displayed but can be changed.

There are to-one references which are editable NSObjects itself where 1 and exactly 1 of them exists.

There are to-many references which can be added, deleted and edited. Pretty similar to the calendar app or the address book app. (from a functional point of view. It looks different though).

For that I establish a delegate between the table cells and the view controller. This is mainly because I try to stick on the MVC pattern.

E.G. the cell serves as delegate for `UITextViews`, `UITextFields` or as target for Buttons etc. 
The (Detail-) View controller which owns the `NSManagedObject` and all related objects serves as my delegate for the cells. It provides methods similar to IBActions to the cells so that the cell can 1) inform about the event and 2) hand over a related view, if required (I need that to display some popups accordingly) and 3) the object itself e.g. the object that is to be deleted or a person-object for which the data is to be fetched from the address book etc. 
The View controller can then does its very own duties which is invoking other view controllers (Send Mail, select from Address Book, present a popover with options for the user to choose from, ...).

I just built that up yesterday evening. (It is a free-time project of mine). 
I am happy so far but the concept is not really proven yet :) .

What is your current favorite approach?